# Google Play Billing Library, где ее взять, если ее нет

Tags: android, android-studio

Подскажите плз, не могу в своей студии найти Google Play Billing Library. Открываю sdk manager и ее просто там нет. Подскажите, может не там ищу. Спасибо.

Comment: А зачем её искать? Вот дока где показано как её в одну строку подключить: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/getting-ready

Comment: Я ее и подключил таким образом. Но IInAppBillingService продолжает светится красным((.я первый раз это делаю. И могу ерунду спрашивать, так что сори.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что  необходимо добавить файл IInAppBillingService, где его тогда взять

Comment: IInAppBillingService не нужен. Он нужен для устаревшего способа встраивания покупок

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, где посмотреть готовые примеры нового способа.

Comment: Такое вряд-ли где-то есть. У всех всё сильно отличается. Проще просто сделать следуя документации

Comment: ok, спасибо. буду разбираться

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте в build.gradle файл модуля app зависимость на эту библиотеку

```
dependencies {
    def billing_version = "3.0.0"

    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version'
    //Если вы используете котлин то и эту зависимость для extention функций
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing-ktx:$billing_version'
}
```

Синхронизируйте проект с градл файлами File - Sync project with gradle files

Подробная [документация](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate)